Why one of the label bars have their name omited in the graph displayed on Jupyter Notebook?
I have the multiindex dataframe (example below but not complete) named "pivot_dftable" and the code below displaying the analysis I need for it.

I would like to understand why in the graph displayed with the code provided, instead of one of the bar labels in the graph to be named "Re-Open" it just show blank in the graph.

Also, as you can see, the Queue Category names down below the graph is being cut in the image, how could I display it?


Thank you so much for the help!
pivot_dftable =
    Status                                                            New  \
Queue Category                        Ticket Age - Open Tickets         
UAE Queue                             Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          1.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          1.0   
Switzerland Queue                     Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           1.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week            1.0   
HQ Queue                              Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           1.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week            1.0   
London Queue                          Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          2.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           0.0   
York Queue                            Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          0.0   
Denmark Queue                         Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          0.0   
Finland Queue                         Older than 3 Months         3.0   
Norway Queue                          Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          2.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          0.0   
Sweden Queue                          Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           3.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week            4.0   
France Queue                          Older than 3 Months         7.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          4.0   
Netherlands Queue                     Older than 3 Months         3.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month         14.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks         14.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           4.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week            0.0   
Spain Queue                           Older than 3 Months         2.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          1.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          3.0   
Czech Queue                           Older than 3 Months         1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
Slovakia Queue                        Older than 3 Months         1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          3.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          1.0   
Portugal Queue                        Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          4.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          2.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           2.0   
Peru Queue                            Older than 3 Months        16.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          1.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          1.0   
TMC Queue                             Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          1.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          5.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week          13.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week           14.0   
CoE - Compensation & Benefits         Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          1.0   
CoE - Talent Acquisition              Older than 1 Month          0.0   
CoE - Learning, Development & Culture Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
Global - Hypercare                    Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
Global - HR Business Partners         Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          2.0   
Global Central HRIS Team Queue        Older than 3 Months         2.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          1.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           5.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week            9.0   
AMS Queue                             Older than 3 Months         0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month          0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks          0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week           0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week            0.0   

Status                                                           In Progress  \
Queue Category                        Ticket Age - Open Tickets                
UAE Queue                             Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Switzerland Queue                     Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  2.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   2.0   
HQ Queue                              Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   0.0   
London Queue                          Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  0.0   
York Queue                            Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Denmark Queue                         Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Finland Queue                         Older than 3 Months                0.0   
Norway Queue                          Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Sweden Queue                          Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 2.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 3.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  5.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   4.0   
France Queue                          Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Netherlands Queue                     Older than 3 Months                3.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 3.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   0.0   
Spain Queue                           Older than 3 Months                2.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Czech Queue                           Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
Slovakia Queue                        Older than 3 Months                1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
Portugal Queue                        Older than 3 Months                4.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 3.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  0.0   
Peru Queue                            Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 0.0   
TMC Queue                             Older than 3 Months                4.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                13.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                12.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  3.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   0.0   
CoE - Compensation & Benefits         Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
CoE - Talent Acquisition              Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
CoE - Learning, Development & Culture Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
Global - Hypercare                    Older than 3 Months                1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 1.0   
Global - HR Business Partners         Older than 3 Months                0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 0.0   
Global Central HRIS Team Queue        Older than 3 Months                7.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                26.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                12.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  4.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   3.0   
AMS Queue                             Older than 3 Months                2.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month                 1.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks                 7.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week                  1.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week                   6.0   

Status                                                           Re-Open  \
Queue Category                        Ticket Age - Open Tickets            
UAE Queue                             Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Switzerland Queue                     Older than 3 Months            6.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             5.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              1.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   
HQ Queue                              Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   
London Queue                          Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
York Queue                            Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Denmark Queue                         Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Finland Queue                         Older than 3 Months            0.0   
Norway Queue                          Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Sweden Queue                          Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             3.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   
France Queue                          Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Netherlands Queue                     Older than 3 Months            2.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   
Spain Queue                           Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Czech Queue                           Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
Slovakia Queue                        Older than 3 Months            1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
Portugal Queue                        Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
Peru Queue                            Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
TMC Queue                             Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   
CoE - Compensation & Benefits         Older than 3 Months            1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
CoE - Talent Acquisition              Older than 1 Month             0.0   
CoE - Learning, Development & Culture Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
Global - Hypercare                    Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
Global - HR Business Partners         Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
Global Central HRIS Team Queue        Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             3.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             1.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   
AMS Queue                             Older than 3 Months            0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0   
                                      Older than 2 Weeks             0.0   
                                      Older than 1 Week              0.0   
                                      Less than 1 Week               0.0   

Status                                                           Waiting  
Queue Category                        Ticket Age - Open Tickets           
UAE Queue                             Older than 3 Months            0.0  
                                      Older than 1 Month             0.0  
   

Code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox, TextArea

# Assuming pivot_df is your DataFrame
# Map the "Queue Category" column using the dictionary
pivot_df.index = pivot_dftable.index.set_levels(pivot_dftable.index.levels[0].map(queuetocountry), level=0)

# Filter the DataFrame to include only the specified countries
countrieslist = ['AE', 'CH', 'London', 'York', 'DK', 'FI', 'NO', 'SE', 'FR', 'NL', 'ES', 'CZ', 'SK', 'PT', 'PE', 'TMC', 'HRIS', 'AMS']
filtered_df = pivot_df[pivot_df.index.get_level_values('Queue Category').isin(countrieslist)]

# Print the filtered DataFrame to debug
print(filtered_df)

# Define queue categories and ticket ages
queue_categories = filtered_df.index.get_level_values('Queue Category').unique()
ticket_ages = ['Older than 3 Months', 'Older than 1 Month', 'Older than 2 Weeks', 'Older than 1 Week', 'Less than 1 Week']
statuses = ['New', 'In Progress', 'Re-Open', 'Waiting']

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))

# Define colors for each ticket age category
colors = {
    'Older than 3 Months': 'red',
    'Older than 1 Month': 'orange',
    'Older than 2 Weeks': 'yellow',
    'Older than 1 Week': 'green',
    'Less than 1 Week': 'blue'
}
width = 0.2  # width of the bars

x = np.arange(len(queue_categories))
n = len(statuses)

# Loop through each status to create the grouped bars
for i, status in enumerate(statuses):
    bottom = np.zeros(len(queue_categories))
    for ticket_age in ticket_ages:
        try:
            current_counts = filtered_df.loc[(slice(None), ticket_age), status].reindex(queue_categories, fill_value=0).values
        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"KeyError for status '{status}' and ticket_age '{ticket_age}': {e}")
            current_counts = np.zeros(len(queue_categories))
        bars = ax.bar(x + (i - n / 2) * width, current_counts, bottom=bottom, width=width, color=colors[ticket_age], edgecolor='white', label=f'{ticket_age}' if i == 0 else None)
        bottom += current_counts
        
        # Add the total value on top of each bar
        for bar in bars:
            height = bar.get_height()
            if height > 0:  # Only annotate if the height is greater than 0
                ax.annotate(f'{int(height)}',
                            xy=(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, bar.get_y() + height),
                            xytext=(0, 0),  # 3 points vertical offset
                            textcoords="offset points",
                            ha='center', va='bottom')

# Set labels and title
ax.set_title('9.1 Open Ticket Ages by Queue Category and Status', fontsize=15)

# Set x-ticks and labels for queue categories
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels([])  # Clear the existing labels

# Add status labels below the bars
status_labels = [f'{status}' for status in statuses for _ in range(len(queue_categories))]
status_positions = np.tile(x, n) + np.repeat((np.arange(n) - n / 2) * width, len(queue_categories))
ax.set_xticks(status_positions, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(status_labels, minor=True, rotation=90, fontsize=8, ha='center')

# Move queue category labels down by 2 cm
for i, label in enumerate(queue_categories):
    offsetbox = TextArea(label, textprops=dict(rotation=90, ha='center', va='top', fontsize=10))
    ab = AnnotationBbox(offsetbox, (x[i], 0), xybox=(0, -60),  # Move down by 60 points (approx 5 cm)
                        xycoords='data', boxcoords="offset points", frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)

# Adjust layout to prevent overlap and increase bottom margin
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)

# Create a legend with only the "Ticket Aging" categories
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
unique_labels = {}
for handle, label in zip(handles, labels):
    if label not in unique_labels:
        unique_labels[label] = handle
ax.legend(unique_labels.values(), unique_labels.keys(), title='Ticket Age')

plt.show()



About cuf-off labels: calling plt.tight_layout() just before plt.show() usually fits everything nicely.

about the blank "Re - Open": this is caused by ax.set_xticklabels([])  # Clear the existing labels as it follows ax.set_xticks(x). Replacing ax.set_xticks(x)  by ax.set_xticks([]) and removing ax.set_xticklabels([]) will probably solve your issue. Matplotlib works with "major" and "minor" ticks.  When a minor tick is at the some position as a major tick, the minor tick is ignored.

Thank you so much @JohanC, for what really mattered you helped with the solution. By the way, tight_layout is not working, still cutting the bottom names like showing. I was thinking in some way to increase size of the image with more white space by the bottom?

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3) or something similar might work in your case.  Here bottom=0.3 means 30% of the "figure height" is used for the region of the plot under the x-axis. (tight_layout() doesn't work here, because the text is placed via an AnnotationBbox).
